# Expo Image Flashing when new images appended to state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently working on constructing a Masonry List, and I've encountered an issue with the Image component from the expo-image package. There seems to be an unwanted transitioning or easing effect – a sort of flashing – whenever a new image is added to the list. I am pretty sure that it's not a rendering issue. When I remove the component it works well without any image. Could you please help me about it?

Here is my Image view component:

````
import { Image } from "expo-image";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const RemoteImage = ({ uri, dimension, borderRadius = 15 }) => {
    const [ratio, setRatio] = useState(1);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    let counter = 0;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setRatio(dimension?.small.width / dimension?.small.height);
    },[]);

  return (
        <View style={{overflow:'hidden', position:'relative', backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7', width:'100%', aspectRatio: ratio, borderRadius: borderRadius}}>
            <Image
                source={uri}
                style={[styles.image, { aspectRatio: ratio, borderRadius }]}
                contentFit="cover"
                transition={1000}
                accessible={true}
                cachePolicy='memory-disk'
                onLoadStart={() => setLoading(true)}
                onLoadEnd={() => setLoading(false)}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: "100%"
    }
});

export default RemoteImage;```
````

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "flash" is happening at the moment react-native is loading the image, does the flash become red if you change

```js
backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7'
```

to

```js
backgroundColor:'#FF0000'
```

if yes then just change the background color while loading, else can you show a gif of what's happening please

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not a rendering issue? Did you check this with the de tools? Also, you could add a console.log in your code to double check.

It may be that you are changing the props without realizing it.

If you are changing the props, you may want to check out [React.memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo)

To change this out, please change your examport to the following:

```
export default React.memo(RemoteImage, arePropsEqual);
```

And add this method to your component:

```
const arePropsEqual = (oldProps, newProps) => {
  return oldProps.uri === newProps.uri &&
    oldProps.dimension === newProps.dimension &&
    oldProps.borderRadius === newProps.borderRadius;
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added a code example. Hope that helps!